Point inside circle
I want to check if a point Q is inside a circle (P1, P2, P3) but I'm having problems when the point is part of the circle because the last condition return it as false when it should be true, this is because of float precision.
    public static bool QTest(Vector3 P1 ,Vector3 P2, Vector3 P3, Vector3 Q)//Test if the point Q is inside the circumcircle of P1, P2, P3
    {
        Vector3 midPoint1 = MidPoint(P1, P2);
        float pSlope = -1 / ((P2.z - P1.z) / (P2.x - P1.x)); 

        Vector3 midPoint2 = MidPoint(P2, P3);
        float pSlope2 = -1 / ((P3.z - P2.z) / (P3.x - P2.x));

        //formula y - midPoint.z = perpendicularSlope * (x - midPoint.x)

        float x = (- pSlope2 * midPoint2.x + midPoint2.z + pSlope * midPoint1.x - midPoint1.z) / (pSlope - pSlope2);
        float y = pSlope * (x - midPoint1.x) + midPoint1.z;

        Vector3 center = new(x, 0, y);

        float epsilon = 1e-3f;

        float radius = (center - P1).sqrMagnitude;
        float distance2 = (center - Q).sqrMagnitude;

        if (distance2 < radius - epsilon) return false;
        return true;
    }


If your problem is float precision, then you need to define what you mean by inside, by outside, and, if applicable, on the circle. To do that, you need to relax some of your definitions (for example, on means within X of true). You are already using an epsilon in your calculations, you probably need to sit down and decide how much slop is applicable to your situation (trigonometry can confuse things)

Some things to think about: You have coordinates of three points. How accurately do those coordinates represent the desired points? Do they have rounding errors from prior calculations? How much, can you specify an upper bound? You calculate the center of a circle. How much rounding error is there in that, can you figure out a bound on it? Does it depend on the points or the location of the center (possibly more error if some of the coordinates are large numbers, due to larger rounding errors)?…

… You calculate the radius of the circle and the distance to point Q. How much rounding error is there in that? Finally, if interval determined by the distance to point Q allowing for rounding errors overlaps the interval for the radius of the circle allowing for rounding errors, do you want to always accept Q as being inside the circle? What happens if that makes you accept Q as being inside the circle when it is actually not?

@m Using float epsilon = 1e-3f; or some other fixed radius - epsilon is a mistake.  Floating point numbers deserve a relative compare.  Something like (distance2 - radius)/radius < epsilon.

You probably want radius + epsilon instead of radius - epsilon if you want to include the border (imagine you are increasing the radius of the circle a bit to include the border). Maybe you also have to swap true and false, because currently the function will return true when the point is outside the circle.

Since I wanted the points on the circle to be excluded I still substract the epsilon to the radius. With a bigger epsilon float epsilon = 1e-2f it seems to work just fine and I still think is small enough on my specific case.
With this set up and after testing it if (distance2 > radius - epsilon) return true works fine thanks for the help.
